# remove .html/ and redirect to new URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to do 2 steps in a re-direct. I'm trying to redirect from

`www.example.com/02/11/name-of-post.html/`

to

`www.exampleblog.com/02/11/name-of-post`

So I'm going from a different url where the post ends with .html/

I can remove the .html, however it seems the trailing slash causes an issue.

`www.example.com/02/11/name-of-post.html/` - this won't redirect

`www.example.com/02/11/name-of-post.html` - this will

```
#remove .html from posts
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a directory/folder called 'name-of-post' then call the file actually containing the html 'index.html', if you want name-of-post to appear as /name-of-post/. If you add a slash (/) after the URL then the computer will treat it as a directory, not an individual webpage.